# Import file from memory dynamically

Tags: python-2.7, import, module

I have variable with python module. I want to import it, to get its variables.
Memory python file contents looks like:

```
# import smth
aaa = {'mykey1':'myval1','mykey2':'myval2','mykey3':'myval3','mykey4':'myval4'}
bbb = ['mykey1', 'mykey2']
ccc = 'some string'
ddd = 17
#eee = 18
...  and so on
```

I want to create no tmp files, unless in memory.

Comment: does `eval` do what you need it to do?

Comment: Rick Rongen, got 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax'


while running line
'eval(my_inmemory_file_string)'

Comment: My bad `eval` only works for expressions (e.g. `eval("5+5")` -> `10`), not for assignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute a python script from a string using the `exec` function. If you want to get the globals defined in the script you need to give it a object/dict to use for that. Example:

```
script = "# import smth\naaa = {'mykey1':'myval1','mykey2':'myval2','mykey3':'myval3','mykey4':'myval4'}\nbbb = ['mykey1', 'mykey2']\nccc = 'some string'\nddd = 17\n#eee = 18"
results = {}
exec(script, result)
print result['ddd']  # 17
```

Please do make sure you trust the code you are executing because it runs with the same permissions as your program.